# change variable declared in out scope or access it

Tags: c#

I do not want to declare `x` variable but I wanna increment `out y`. Is it possible? Albahari code. The problem is `y=1` is always initializing. I want to check if `y` exists then `y = y + 1;` and `y = 0` otherwise.  wanna access and increment variable created via out not by me.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppX
{
    class D
    {
        static void Foo(out int y)
        {
            y = 1;
            y = y + 1; // Mutate y
        }

       // static int x;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo(out int x);
            Foo(out  x);
            Foo(out x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What should "if `y` exists" mean? `int` is a _value_ type, so if you can call `Foo`, `y` _does_ exist. It cannot _not_ exist.

Comment: What does "check if y exists" mean? It's an int. It has to exist, always.

Comment: What you _could_ do is: `static int Foo(int? y)` then you do not need to init, y could be null and you can return respectively. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/v9Zz2G

Comment: Exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: wanna access and increment variable created via out not by me.

Comment: @ifooi In that case you have to initialize it yourself. The inline `out int` is not meant for something you would usually use `ref` for, for that exact reason I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont know what you are trying do :)
But Out method required Parameter to assign some value.

If you dont want assign any value and Just Manipulate the passed value 
You can use **ref**

So your code may look like,

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppX
{
    class D
    {
        static void Foo(ref int y)
        {
            //y = 1;
            y = y + 1; // Mutate y
        }

       // static int x;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 0;
            Foo(ref x);
            Foo(ref x);
            Foo(ref x);
            Console.WriteLine(x);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Obvious but I do not wanna write int x = 0; I think it is stupid but I wanna access and increment variable  created via out not by me.

Comment: @ifooi You are not supposed to know what an `out` parameters initial value even was. You are trying to combine `out` and `ref`, that won't work. There is a reason we have `in`, `out` and `ref` keywords and not just pointers like in C/C++.

Comment: _"I do not wanna write int x = 0;"_ Why? Do you have _one good_ reason? I do not see _any_ benefit in doing it (if it were at all possible).

Comment: What the benefits of outs then?

Comment: @ifooi `out` means the variable is only used to **receive** a value. `in` means it's **not** going to be modified inside the function and `ref` means you can modify it (basically turning it into a by-reference value). That's why you can initialize variables with an `out` parameter because it doesn't matter what value it has when it goes into the function - the function **must** assign a new value.

Comment: Tnank you, guys!